# Python matched the value on json response based on user input, and pass the value to variable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, request

please give the solution based on my code below, and also can you help me, so in order to enter the country name, user must see the country list first, i mean in first step user must input 'country' and then it gives response the 'c_list' like in the screenshot, and then user can input the country they choose, so it was like there was a step before you can input country name  :)

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

c_list = ['Australia', 'CHINA', 'Combodia', 'EUROPE', 'HONG KONG','INDIA',         
'INDONESIA', 'JAPAN', 'KOREA', 'MALAYSIA', 'Myanmar', 'New Zealand', 
'PHILIPPINES', 'Russia', 'senchilles', 'SINGAPORE', 'Sri Lanka', 'TAIWAN', 
'TestCountry', 'THAILAND', 'UNITED KINGDOM', 'USA', 'Vietnam',    
'XYTestCountry']
r = input(" user input : ")
wt = (word_tokenize(r))
if any("country" in s for s in wt):
  reply = c_list
else:
  reply = "Sorry I cant answer that right now."

print(reply)
```

[image]

the result above is from api response

my question is, how can i add code that can check if the country exist in the 'c_list' list when user reply any country listed above.
Then if its exist i want to pass the country code on this json if matched with user reply, then i want to pass the country code to another api request and so on

```
"DATA": {
     "data":[
         {
            "countryId": "26",
            "countryCode" : "AU",
            "name" : "Australia"
         },
         {
            "countryId": "17",
            "countryCode" : "ID",
            "name" : "Indonesia"
         }
       ]
     }
```

Comment: edit your code please

Comment: i changed the array from 's' to 'c_list' @AmirNaimi

Comment: your code has syntax error

Comment: there is no if for the last else  ---->> else:
  response.status = falcon.HTTP_200
  response.body = "Message was sent in a wrong format."

Comment: i edited it sorry @AmirNaimi

Answer (score 0):

Here are some snippets to give you a good start.

Say user response is `rv` holding country name. Check if country exists in 'c_list'.

```
country_lower = rv.lower()

is_in_country_list = country_lower in map(str.lower, c_list)
```

Parse country code from JSON sample.

```
countries = {
    "DATA": {
        "data": [{
            "countryId": "26",
            "countryCode": "AU",
            "name": "Australia"
        }, {
            "countryId": "17",
            "countryCode": "ID",
            "name": "Indonesia"
        }]
    }
}


def take_first(predicate, iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if predicate(element):
            yield element
            break

country_found = list(
    take_first(
        lambda e: e['name'].lower() == country_lower, 
        countries['DATA']['data']
    )
)

default_country_code = 'US'
country_code = (
    country_found['countryCode'] 
    if country_found 
    else default_country_code
)
```

Comment: "i get this error"

user input : country
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    is_in_country_list = country_lower in map(lower, c_list)
NameError: name 'lower' is not defined

Comment: That should be `str.lower` and not `lower`

Comment: and also can you help me, so in order to enter the country name, user must see the country list first, i mean in first step user must input 'country' and then it gives response the 'c_list' like in the screenshot, and then user can input the country they choose, so it was like there was a step before you can input country name :)